# Inheritance of parent ontology attributes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, protege

When constructing ontology, there will be parent and child classes. The attributes of the parent ontology created in neo4j are generally only related to the parent ontology. How to make the child ontology inherit the attributes of the parent ontology?

Comment: Explain the problem more in detail. If you link child and parent you shouldn't have a problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.